# Java JSONArray - comparing elements with other elements within the same JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Am comparing javascript array of elements with other elements within the same array. If elements are same means, I have to give the same number for all the common elements. If the elements are different I have to give some different number for all the nonidentical elements in another element.

for example :

```
Array structure = [{Location, Date, Number}]
array = [{ 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
     { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
     { 'NY','2017-12-01',2},
     { 'NY','2016-10-01',3},
     { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
     { 'LA','2017-12-01',1},
     { 'LA','2017-12-01',1}]
```

In this array 'Number' is dynamic element, It should be populate on the following rules.

```
`key1 = location + '-' +date;`
```

Consider Key1 is the first element ( combination of location + date ). If the same key1 is present in the array, then 'Number' is common for all the same Key1.

In the above example `{'LA','2017-12-01',1 }` having the same number 1.

`{ 'NY','2017-12-01',2}` having the number 2. and  `{ 'NY','2016-10-01',3}`, having the number  3 because eventhough location is common but date is different.

Please find my code below that am trying. But it giving same number for all the array elements.

```
JSONObject orderObj=database.getOrder(salesorderId);
JSONArray lineArr = orderObj.getJSONArray("order_items"); //lines
JSONObject lineObj = null;
for(int i=0;i<lineArr.length();i++)
{
lineObj = lineArr.getJSONObject(i);
String source_location=lineObj.getString("source_location");
String key=source_location.concat(lineObj.has("ship_date") ? 
lineObj.getString("ship_date") : lineObj.getString("req_ship_date"));
Map map=new HashMap();
if(!map.containsKey(key)){
map.put(key, map.size()+1);
}
lineObj.put("number", map.get(key).toString());
}
orderObj.append("order_items", lineObj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the instantiating of `map` out of the `for` loop:

```
JSONObject orderObj = database.getOrder(salesorderId);
JSONArray lineArr = orderObj.getJSONArray("order_items"); //lines
JSONObject lineObj = null;
// To here:
Map map = new HashMap();
for ( int i = 0; i < lineArr.length(); ++i )
{
  lineObj = lineArr.getJSONObject(i);
  String source_location = lineObj.getString("source_location");
  String key = source_location.concat( lineObj.has("ship_date") ?
               lineObj.getString("ship_date") : lineObj.getString("req_ship_date"));
  // From here: Map map=new HashMap();
  if ( !map.containsKey(key) )
  {
    map.put(key, map.size() + 1);
  }
  lineObj.put("number", map.get(key).toString());
}
orderObj.append("order_items", lineObj);
```

Comment: `orderObj.append("order_items", lineObj);` due to this line, its creating duplicate entry in MongoDB., How to update the same `order_items`array instead of creating new JSONObject of `order_items`